# Proving a language is Turing recognizable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, turing-machines

Turing Machine M with a `wait` option has the option to make the machine's head `wait` where it is, until a case comes along where the `wait` option is not used. I am trying to show that such a Turing machine recognizes the class of Turing recognizable languages.

I have been trying to brainstorm how to begin to show this, however, I am having a difficult time proving this for the 'class' of Turing recognizable languages, as it is so general.

I would appreciate if someone can give me some suggestions, as to how I should proceed with this proof.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please explain what `WAIT` means here. A Turing machine lives alone in it's universe, there is nothing else which could make the `WAIT` end, so I'm lost.

Comment: @vonbrand: It seems to make the best sense to interpret "wait" as an alternative to "left" and "right", such that one can specify "in state $s_1$, seeing symbol $a_1$, write $a_2$ and go to state $s_2$ _without moving the tape head_".

Comment: @HenningMakholm, that can be simulated by e.g. writing $a_2$ and move right, there write the symbol that is already there and move left.

Answer (score 1):

Take a machine $M$ with `wait` instructions, and transform it into a machine $M'$ that does the same thing but without using `wait`.  For example, suppose when $M$ is in state $S$ and scans symbol $i$ on the tape, it goes into state $T$ and the head `wait`s.  Then $M'$ should have a state $S$, and when it scans symbol $i$ on the tape, it should go into state $S'$ and move the head to the right.  Then in state $S'$ it should move the head left again, no matter what is on the tape, and go into state $T$.  Now $M'$ goes into  from state $S$ into state $T$ exactly like $M$ would have, except that instead of using `wait` to hold the tape head still, it moved it right and then left.